# Вставить, удалить, изменить записи в БД

Tags: c#, ado.net

Столкнулся с проблемой: Как вставить/удалить/обновить записи в базе данных?
Хочу сделать так, что бы пользователь поработал с таблицей, нажал кнопку "Сохранить" и все изменения зафиксировались.

[Проект на GitHub](https://github.com/Algolux113/VOSApp)

Добавление работает, обновление нет, почему не понятно, удаление с ошибкой: нельзя получить данные из удаленной строки. Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне справиться с этой проблемой.

Работаю с формой: "CitiesDialog".

```
/// <summary>
/// Метод обновляет строку в таблице Cities
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cityRow">Редактируемая строка</param>
public void ChangeCity(DataRow cityRow)
{
    string commadString = "UPDATE Cities " +
        "SET CityName = @CityName " +
        "WHERE CityID = @CityID;";

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(commadString, connection);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityID", cityRow["CityID"]);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityName", cityRow["CityName"]);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    cityRow.AcceptChanges();
}

/// <summary>
/// Метод удаляет запись из таблицы Cities
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cityRow">Удаляемая строка</param>
public void DeleteCity(DataRow cityRow)
{
    string commadString = "DELETE Cities " +
        "WHERE CityID = @CityID;";

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(commadString, connection);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityID", cityRow["CityID"]);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
    cityRow.AcceptChanges();
}

/// <summary>
/// Метод вставляет/обновляет/удаляет записи
/// в зависимости от состояния
/// </summary>
/// <param name="cityTable">Изменяемая таблица</param>
public void UpdateCities(DataTable cityTable)
{
    foreach (DataRow city in cityTable.Rows)
    {
        if (city.RowState == DataRowState.Added)
            InsertCity(city);
        if (city.RowState == DataRowState.Modified)
            ChangeCity(city);
        if (city.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted)
            DeleteCity(city);
    }
    cityTable.AcceptChanges();
}

/// <summary>
/// Изменить запись
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["CityID"].Value.ToString();

    DataRow rowToEdit = cities.Rows.Find(id);

    try
    {
        if (textBox1.Text.Count() != 0)
        {
            rowToEdit["CityName"] = textBox1.Text.Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception(cities.Columns["CityName"].Caption + " обязательно для заполнения");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Удалить запись
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string id = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["CityID"].Value.ToString();

    DataRow rowToDelete = cities.Rows.Find(id);

    try
    {
        rowToDelete.Delete();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Сохранить изменения в таблице
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        dal.UpdateCities(cities);
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
    }
    finally
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашей таблице нет удаленных строк - они же были удалены! Поэтому вы их и не получаете в цикле `foreach`.

Попробуйте воспользоваться методом [`GetChanges()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.datatable.getchanges(v=vs.110).aspx) для получения изменений включая удаленные строки.

Comment: С удалением разобрался, но пришлось изменить входные параметры для метода. GetChanges() пригодился, цикл проходит только по изменённым строкам, хотя возможно я его не правильно применил. Вопрос с обновлением записей всё ещё актуален. Ни каких ошибок, методы отрабатывают, но ничего не происходит.

Comment: А с обновлением-то что не так? Вы отлаживать пробовали?

Comment: Да пробовал, метод отрабатывает, в него передаются правильные параметры. Эксепшенов не возникает. Пробовал и запрос менять и параметры, Открыл форму, изменил табличку, сохранил изменения, открыл заново, ничего. И в бд тоже.

Comment: Так не бывает. Где-то должно возникать исключение.

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю, что RowState.Deleted ставится уже после того, как строка уже была удалена из DataTable. Очевидно, что получить какую-либо информацию по этой строке не получится. Если Вы хотите чтобы изменения сохранялись по всей таблице сразу, то это будет проблематично. Как вариант хранить где-то таблицу перед изменением и потом построчно сравнивать по ключам.

Comment: Возможно вы правы, но я сделал так:

`if (city.RowState == DataRowState.Deleted)
 DeleteCity(city["CityID", DataRowVersion.Original].ToString());`

Вопрос с обновлением всё ещё актуален, никаких ошибок, все методы отрабатывают. Выполнял по шагам, параметры верные передаются, что не так понять не могу.